# Visual Studio Code Include path error in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, header-files, fatal-error, include-path

It seems to be a simple problem but I can't find a solution to it.
I'm having a issues while including the header of a basic function I created.

```
main.c:2:10: fatal error: 'add.h' file not found
#include "add.h"
```

I made this code as simple a possible to highlight the main issue.
Here's my main code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "add.h" //add.c function header


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int num1 = 5, num2 = 6;
    add(num1, num2);
    return 0;
}
```

add.c function code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(int n1, int n2)
{
    int sum = n1 + n2;
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", n1, n2, sum);
}
```

And the add.h

```
void add(int n1, int n2);
```

My c_cpp_properties.json file.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/header"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Project structuration:

- Test_Header(folder)

  - source(folder)

    - main.c
    - add.c
  - header(folder)

    - add.h

I'm on Mac, my editor is Visual studio Code and I run the program with the run button provided by the "code runner" visual studio code extension.
I have a little light bubble on the top of my #include "add.h" saying "add to include path".

My guess is that it comes from the compiler, like he's not looking at the right place for the headers.
 How can I change that (if that's what I need to do)?
 Also, do changing it wouldn't change where he's supposed to find the built in c function library , like stdio ?
 Or he can understand that he has a folder for the standard c function library and an other for user custom headers that should be located in the project directory ?

I've been 3 days on that issue, Couldn't find an answer on the web, or stuff that I couldn't understand. I could switch on an IDE but it will be like giving up.

I'm fairly new in the world of programmation as you can guess, so if you can keep it as simple as possible, it would be great :). 
Thank you.

Comment: Note that `add.c` should include `add.h` — that way you get proper cross-checking that the defined function matches the declared function, and that the consumers of the function (`main()` in your example) are using it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   I just did, but the problem's still the same. add.c can't find the add.h.

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer (mainly because it is tangential to the problem you're having — it should be fixed, but doesn't solve your problem).  Somewhere along the line, you need to add `-I header` or equivalent to the options passed to the C compiler.  I'm not sure how you do that with VS Code.  Clicking on the bubble might help, or clicking where it is pointing at.

Comment: In VSCode, the C_Cpp extension has an includePath setting you can change. You could change it to include `${workspaceFolder}/header`

Comment: @bisen2 Already checked :   I have     ${workspaceFolder}/**     and     
${workspaceFolder}/header

Comment: Do you have a `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file?

Comment: @bisen2 Yes, I just updated the post

Comment: upper / lower case file or directory issue or perhaps permissions?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Not sure where I have to go for the permissions. Tried in the security section of system preferences, in the full access to disque sub section. Hasn't solved the problem.